# Determine datatype parameter for generic used in interface

Tags: c#, class, generics, parameters, interface

I am struggling to find an elegant solution in determining a data type in an interface that was used as a generic parameter in an abstract class.

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Object Identifier
    /// </summary>
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Concrete class:

```
public class Department: Entity<int>
{
  // Additional properties
}

public class Employee: Entity<long>
{
  // Additional properties
}
```

Interface implementation:

```
public interface IService<T1, T2> 
where T1 : Entity<?> 
where T2 : Entity<?>
{
  Task TransferEmployeeToDepartment(? departmentId, ? employeeId);
}
```

A solution to the problem would be to send the data type as an additional parameter but for personal and OCD reasons I prefer not to do so. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Why must the method, named `TransferEmployeeToDepartment`, be generic at all? Why just don't write it this way: `Task TransferEmployeeToDepartment(Department department, Employee employee)`??

Comment: The additional lookup for the Department and Employee object would be an unnecessary overhead to the database as the ids will be passed to the service via a web api from the front end.

Comment: So, you don't want to load those objects from database. OK. If there will be enough to know department Id and employee Id, then write something like this: `Task TransferEmployeeToDepartment(int departmentId, long employeeId)`. What's the reason to use generics here? What generic code should be inside your method?

Comment: @Dennis - Simply to have the flexibility in reusing the interface for other classes such as contractors, nurses etc.

I am merely extending the functionality and can't change the design or data types for that matter so instead of writing an interface for every single one I am trying to go the generic route to make maintenance and support easier.

The interface once implemented will have resolved the data type (int/long) and then just pass the data along to the repositories to be saved in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Dennis comment. According to your method name you transfer concrete class `Employee` to concrete class `Department`. There is nothing generic here. 
So if you want to transfer only these two entities your code should be like this

```
public class Department: Entity<int>
{
  // Additional properties
}

public class Employee: Entity<long>
{
  // Additional properties

    public Department TransferToDepartment() {} //implementation here
}
```

If your goal is to transfer any entity to any another entity i would remake yout interface into the following way

```
public interface IService<T1, T2>
{
    Task TransferEmployeeToDepartment(Entity<T1> entityFrom, Entity<T2> entityTo);
}
```

But if you a set of almost unrelated entities (like Department and Employee) i doubt that it is possible to write some good generic code for this

Comment: Thank you for the interface suggestion, this would definitely work.